# Converting a array to an array of ranges in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

I have an array of numbers. I want to convert it to an array of ranges. Example:

```
input = [0,10,20,30]

output = [0..10, 10..20, 20..30, 30..Infinity]
```

Is there some direct way to do it in Ruby?

Comment: what is that hiphen supposed to mean between the numbers inside the inner array ?

Comment: Is `[0-10]` meant to be `[0, 1, ..., 10]`? Then what is `[30-infinity]`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The title and the text clearly says it is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, possible :

```
input = [0,10,20,30]
(input + [Float::INFINITY]).each_cons(2).map { |a,b| a..b }
 # => [0..10, 10..20, 20..30, 30..Infinity]
```

Comment: You have an array of ranges, but the OP asks for an array of arrays (which does not make sense, given the example). You are not answering the OP's question, but it is not your fault. It is the OP's fault.

Comment: @sawa Humm,, you are right. I assumed he wanted to get array of ranges.

Comment: You could use the shorthand `.map { |a,b| a..b }` instead of `Range.new`

Answer (score 1):

One way:

**Code**

```
output = input.zip(input[1..-1] << 1.0/0).map { |r| Range.new(*r) }
```

**Explanation**

```
input = [0,10,20,30]

a = input[1..-1]
  #=> [10, 20, 30]

b = a << 1.0/0
  #=> [10, 20, 30, Infinity]

c = input.zip(b)
  #=> [[0, 10], [10, 20], [20, 30], [30, Infinity]]

output = c.map { |r| Range.new(*r) }
  #=> [0..10, 10..20, 20..30, 30..Infinity]
```

**Possible alternative**

If you instead wanted an array of arrays, you would just change the block:

```
output = input.zip(input[1..-1] << 1.0/0).map { |f,l| [f..l] }
  #=> [[0..10], [10..20], [20..30], [30..Infinity]]
```